# How to declare global scopes to query builder

Tags: laravel, eloquent, query-builder, laravel-6

I have worked with scopes before but only on models, I was wondering how I can apply a scope to the query builder.

```
DB::table('my_table')->[...]    -> Apply scope1
DB::table('my_table2')->[...]   -> Apply scope2
```

Basically how to map scopes based on the table names but using the builder.

What I want to achieve in the end is: If **model X** (having table:**demo_table**) is used using Eloquent apply **scope1** [good so far], but when I use the builder directly it will also apply **scope1**

Edit: Similar to the Laravel 4 implementation [here](https://softonsofa.com/laravel-query-builder-global-scope-how-to-use-custom-connection-and-query-builder-in-laravel-4/)

Answer (score 0):

May below Trait will help you. I am not sure it is a good approach or not.

```
use App\Http\Traits;

trait CustomQueryBuilder{

    public $query = null;

    public function __construct($table_name) {
        $this->query = DB::table($table_name)
    }

    public function TodayCreated_at(){
        return $query->whereDate('created_at', now()->today());
    }
}
```

Or you can refer to this article. this will help you to how to extend query builder functionality.

[Laravel — Extending Query Builder](https://medium.com/@dennissmink/laravel-extending-query-builder-6524c6571a2)

Answer (score 0):

Laravel's Scope::apply() method requires a Model be passed to it (see: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Scope). You could of course build out something that mimics Scope behavior, but unfortunately Laravel doesn't appear to support DB with its Scope interface directly.